# Update XML stored in a XML column in SQL Server Update

Tags: sql-server

Set Url value by applying filter based on location-type value from given sample.

```
<page id="{Page_ID}" name="" type="dat" size="0" sequence="26" originalpagenumber="26" location_type="3" location="">
<content description="" content_format="26" />
<AdditionalInfo>
    <Url>https://s3-eu-west-1/2019/may//001063/gvb140/683c82a3-b3f5-49ee-a34e-01859e8e2228.mp3</Url>
    <Name />
    <Encoding>audio</Encoding>
    <SecurityType>IBCloud</SecurityType>
</AdditionalInfo>
```

Comment: This is not a question... please clarify: what do you want to change on which condition???

Comment: i want to change Url value by filtering location-type from above xml in sql server

Comment: Your XML is [not valid](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c418723f5f5c52bf152f770ee3d44b4f). It is either missing a closing tag for `<page>` or that tag should have no value like `<page ... />`. Also, please provide the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML you've shared is invalid so I've taken the liberty to make it valid in an effort to show you how I might approach this.

I've made the assumption you're looking to update values in a table somewhere in your environment. You can run this example in SSMS.

**THIS IS MEANT AS AN EXAMPLE ONLY. DO NOT BLINDLY RUN THIS AGAINST PRODUCTION DATA.**

First, I created a mock-up table that holds some page XML data. I assumed that a single XML row could contain multiple `page` nodes with duplicate `location_type` values.

```
DECLARE @Pages TABLE ( page_xml XML );
INSERT INTO @Pages ( page_xml ) VALUES (
'<pages>
  <page id="{Page_ID}" name="" type="dat" size="0" sequence="26" originalpagenumber="26" location_type="3" location="">
    <content description="" content_format="26" />
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <Url>https://s3-eu-west-1/2019/may//001063/gvb140/683c82a3-b3f5-49ee-a34e-01859e8e2228.mp3</Url>
      <Name />
      <Encoding>audio</Encoding>
      <SecurityType>IBCloud</SecurityType>
    </AdditionalInfo>
  </page>
  <page id="{Page_ID}" name="" type="dat" size="0" sequence="27" originalpagenumber="27" location_type="3" location="">
    <content description="" content_format="27" />
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <Url>https://s3-eu-west-1/2019/may//001063/gvb140/683c82a3-b3f5-49ee-a34e-01859e8e2228.mp3</Url>
      <Name />
      <Encoding>audio</Encoding>
      <SecurityType>IBCloud</SecurityType>
    </AdditionalInfo>
  </page>
  <page id="{Page_ID}" name="" type="dat" size="0" sequence="28" originalpagenumber="28" location_type="8" location="">
    <content description="" content_format="28" />
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <Url>https://s3-eu-west-1/2019/may//001063/gvb140/683c82a3-b3f5-49ee-a34e-01859e8e2228.mp3</Url>
      <Name />
      <Encoding>audio</Encoding>
      <SecurityType>IBCloud</SecurityType>
    </AdditionalInfo>
  </page>
</pages>' );
```

Selecting the current results from `@Pages` shows the following XML:

```
<pages>
  <page id="{Page_ID}" name="" type="dat" size="0" sequence="26" originalpagenumber="26" location_type="3" location="">
    <content description="" content_format="26" />
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <Url>https://s3-eu-west-1/2019/may//001063/gvb140/683c82a3-b3f5-49ee-a34e-01859e8e2228.mp3</Url>
      <Name />
      <Encoding>audio</Encoding>
      <SecurityType>IBCloud</SecurityType>
    </AdditionalInfo>
  </page>
  <page id="{Page_ID}" name="" type="dat" size="0" sequence="27" originalpagenumber="27" location_type="3" location="">
    <content description="" content_format="27" />
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <Url>https://s3-eu-west-1/2019/may//001063/gvb140/683c82a3-b3f5-49ee-a34e-01859e8e2228.mp3</Url>
      <Name />
      <Encoding>audio</Encoding>
      <SecurityType>IBCloud</SecurityType>
    </AdditionalInfo>
  </page>
  <page id="{Page_ID}" name="" type="dat" size="0" sequence="28" originalpagenumber="28" location_type="8" location="">
    <content description="" content_format="28" />
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <Url>https://s3-eu-west-1/2019/may//001063/gvb140/683c82a3-b3f5-49ee-a34e-01859e8e2228.mp3</Url>
      <Name />
      <Encoding>audio</Encoding>
      <SecurityType>IBCloud</SecurityType>
    </AdditionalInfo>
  </page>
</pages>
```

There are two pages with a location_type of 3, and one with a location_type of 8.

Next, I declared a few variables which I then used to modify the XML.

```
DECLARE @type INT = 3, @url VARCHAR(255) = 'http://www.google.com';

/* Update each Url text for the specified location_type */
WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM @Pages WHERE page_xml.exist( '//pages/page[@location_type=sql:variable("@type")]/AdditionalInfo/Url[text()!=sql:variable("@url")]' ) = 1 )
UPDATE @Pages
SET
    page_xml.modify( '
        replace value of (//pages/page[@location_type=sql:variable("@type")]/AdditionalInfo/Url/text()[.!=sql:variable("@url")])[1]
        with sql:variable("@url")
    ' );
```

After running the update the XML now contains:

```
<pages>
  <page id="{Page_ID}" name="" type="dat" size="0" sequence="26" originalpagenumber="26" location_type="3" location="">
    <content description="" content_format="26" />
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <Url>http://www.google.com</Url>
      <Name />
      <Encoding>audio</Encoding>
      <SecurityType>IBCloud</SecurityType>
    </AdditionalInfo>
  </page>
  <page id="{Page_ID}" name="" type="dat" size="0" sequence="27" originalpagenumber="27" location_type="3" location="">
    <content description="" content_format="27" />
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <Url>http://www.google.com</Url>
      <Name />
      <Encoding>audio</Encoding>
      <SecurityType>IBCloud</SecurityType>
    </AdditionalInfo>
  </page>
  <page id="{Page_ID}" name="" type="dat" size="0" sequence="28" originalpagenumber="28" location_type="8" location="">
    <content description="" content_format="28" />
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <Url>https://s3-eu-west-1/2019/may//001063/gvb140/683c82a3-b3f5-49ee-a34e-01859e8e2228.mp3</Url>
      <Name />
      <Encoding>audio</Encoding>
      <SecurityType>IBCloud</SecurityType>
    </AdditionalInfo>
  </page>
</pages>
```

Using the `WHILE EXISTS (...` ensures that **all** `Url` nodes for the requested **location_type** are updated. In my example here there are two pages with a value of 3 that are updated, while location_type 8 is left alone.

Basically, what this is doing is updating the `Url` for any `page` with the requested **location_type** to the new **@url** value.

There are two key pieces here, the first being:

```
.exist( '//pages/page[@location_type=sql:variable("@type")]/AdditionalInfo/Url[text()!=sql:variable("@url")]' )
```

Which looks for the requested location_type that doesn't have the new @url value.

And the second:

```
page_xml.modify( '
        replace value of (//pages/page[@location_type=sql:variable("@type")]/AdditionalInfo/Url/text()[.!=sql:variable("@url")])[1]
        with sql:variable("@url")
    ' );
```

Which modifies (updates) the Url for the location type that has yet to be updated. The two "conditions" allow for a loop (WHILE) that ends when they're no longer met, ensuring that all page nodes for the requested location_type are updated.